# Trying to get 1080p live feed from HD webcam using Qt and OpenCV only get 480p

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, webcam

I am trying to get full HD processing using Qt and OpenCV, I can only get 480p at the moment, as you can see in the code I have got the width and height of the frame. I have also tried setting the size of the using cvSize(1920 x 1080) but it doesn't change the resolution.

Many thanks for any help!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  VideoCapture cap(1); //capture webcam

  if (!cap.isOpened()) //if not successful then exit
  {
    qDebug() << "Cannot open webcam";
    return -1;
  }

  namedWindow("Camera feed", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create window

  double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get width of frames of video
  double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get height of frames of video
  Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));

  qDebug() << "Frame size = " << dWidth << "x" << dHeight << endl;

  VideoWriter oVideoWriter("video.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), 20, frameSize);

  if(!oVideoWriter.isOpened())
  {
    qDebug() << "ERROR: Failed to write the video" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  while(1)
  {
    Mat frame;
    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); //read a new frame from video

    if(!bSuccess) //if unsuccessful, break loop
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot read frame from video file" << endl;
        break;
    }

    oVideoWriter.write(frame); //write the frame into the file
    imshow("Camera feed", frame); //show the frame in "Live Feed" window

    qDebug() << "Recording" << endl;

    if (waitKey(30) == 27)

    {
      qDebug() << "Esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting forcing your capture to HD by setting the properties:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
```

If so, check if this resolution is supported by the device in other programs like guvcview or v4l2-ctl. If you have the last one installed you can check the supported modes with:
`v4l2-ctl --list-formats`